# Android - SlidingDrawer handle at the right top corner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-ndk

I am working with the android Sliding Drawer and have it working more or less. However, I am running into one problem.

I want it to slide from the right to left which works fine (set orientation to horizontal). However, the handle for the sliding drawer is at the center right of the screen. Is there anyway I can position it at the top right hand corner of the screen? Perhaps with a padding fo 20dp at the top?

There is a SlidingDrawer 'android:topOffset' property. However, this does not seem to do anything irrespective of whether I put the property on the slidingDrawer tag itself or on the handle (ImageView) tag.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @roro- Did you finally achieved this type of functionality...???